# gawk is crashing for complex regexp when LANG is set to .UTF-8 on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, awk

The following command will crash on my system when the `LANG` environment variable is set to eg. `en_US.UTF-8`, but will work fine with `LANG=C`:

```
/usr/bin/gawk '
  BEGIN {
    match(str, /^([^\1-\71\73-\100\133-\136\140\173-\177]|(([\302-\337][\200-\277])|(\340[\240-\277][\200-\277])|([\341-\354\356\357][\200-\277][\200-\277])|(\355[\200-\237][\200-\277])|(\360[\220-\277][\200-\277][\200-\277])|([\361-\363][\200-\277][\200-\277][\200-\277])|(\364[\200-\217][\200-\277][\200-\277])))([^\1-\54\57\73-\100\133-\136\140\173-\177]|(([\302-\337][\200-\277])|(\340[\240-\277][\200-\277])|([\341-\354\356\357][\200-\277][\200-\277])|(\355[\200-\237][\200-\277])|(\360[\220-\277][\200-\277][\200-\277])|([\361-\363][\200-\277][\200-\277][\200-\277])|(\364[\200-\217][\200-\277][\200-\277])))*/) }'
```

The error output is

```
gawk: cmd. line:3: fatal error: internal error: segfault
```

Looking at the core dump, the crash happens in the generated yacc parser for the AWK language (specifically in the yacc regexp lib `dfacomp()` routine). This doesn't happen on eg. Debian 8.6 nor on other Linuxen I tested.

Is this a known problem? Asking because the issue might be that my system has been upgraded from 15.10.

Comment: `gawk --version` ?

Comment: @glennjackman `GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)`